# Linux Mint 13 (Maya / Cinnamon) three-finger middle click

Tags: linux-mint, touchpad

How can I get Linux Mint 13 (Maya/Cinnamon) to recognize three finger clicks as a middle click? I've poked around to no avail. Thanks!

Comment: Does your trackpad support three-finger gestures?

Comment: Yep. Two finger touch is right click. I'd like both. Two finger scroll also works.